# Unable to build wheels in pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I have recently moved to `pipenv` from using the traditional `requirements.txt` file and its not going too well. I am trying to build wheels for one of my Python modules and I always get an error while doing so. The error is:

```
$ pipenv run python -m build --wheel
* Creating virtualenv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0, wheel)
* Getting build dependencies for wheel...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\.virtualenvs\uHugo-eCFFAdEE\lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\.virtualenvs\uHugo-eCFFAdEE\lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\.virtualenvs\uHugo-eCFFAdEE\lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kshagp3u\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kshagp3u\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kshagp3u\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "C:\Users\gollaha\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-kshagp3u\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
```

I am using `toml` and it's installed too. Here is my `Pipfile`:

```ini
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
click = "<=9.0.0,>=8.0.3"
packaging = ">=21.0,<24.0"
requests = "<=3.0.0,>=2.26.0"
toml = ">=0.10.0"
pyyaml = ">=6.0,<=7.0"
psutil = ">=5.8.0,<=6.0.0"
rich = ">=10.12.0,<14.0.0"
pydantic = ">=1.8.2,<=2.0.0"

[dev-packages]
sphinx = "*"
sphinx-tabs = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"
requests-mock = "*"
pytest-subprocess = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
codecov = "*"
coverage = "*"
pytest-runner = "*"
flake8 = "*"
pipenv = "*"
build = "*"
```

To build I did `pipenv run python -m build --wheel`, and this gives me the above error. I also tried running in it's shell via `pipenv shell` but I still get the same error. Not sure what mistake I am doing.

Any help in this is appreciated.

**Update**

Here is the GitHub link of the module - https://github.com/akshaybabloo/uHugo

Comment: Have you already done `pipenv install`? You need to first install packages to use them inside an venv.

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes, I did.